# Can a wizard's bonded object be a sheathed weapon?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, weapons, wizard

In Pathfinder, wizards are often required to have a bonded item which is in the form of a amulet, ring, staff, wand or weapon. I was reading a [guide to wizards](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1xjPIOH8F8a0l74BdDF7Q23nCfZ-YX68Xr6JmmtznMw4/preview) which lamented about the loss of the magic item slot (which I can agree with).

But after reading the [arcane bond](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard#TOC-Arcane-Bond-Ex-or-Sp-) entry, it describes how it must be worn or in hand. I take it that if you got the weapon and just wore it on your side then it would not be sufficient?

Comment: Note that it's not a total loss as an item slot; you get a pass on a feat to turn the arcane bonded object into a magical item, so if it's a ring you can enchant it as if you had Forge Ring.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If the object is an amulet or ring, it must be worn to have effect, while staves, wands, and **weapons must be held in one hand.** [Source (PFSRD)](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard#TOC-Arcane-Bond-Ex-or-Sp-)

Unfortunately no. And It doesn't matter whether is stays in the sheath or not, as long as you're holding it.

Comment: I would argue that it could still be sheathed as long as its held in hand. Just not helpful for hitting people with it, lol.

Comment: @Fering Haha edited. When I wrote it I just pictured someone holding the sword, sheath still at the hip. I didn't mean to imply it *had to be* unsheathed, but rather didn't consider that they may unhook it and hold the whole ensemble lol.

Comment: Also adds the bizarre thought that wizards can't have two handed weapons as foci by RAW, no Quarterstaff for Gandalf

Comment: @Rob Apparently they just have to remove one hand before they can use it properly haha. Though, I don't think RAI that the emphasis should be on *one hand* moreso than *held.*

Answer (score -1):

If the object is an amulet or ring, it must be worn to have effect, while staves, wands, and
weapons must be **wielded**. This plainly states that weapons must be wielded! Beside how great would it be for the GM when the player with a bonded Bastard Sword has to pull his weapon to cast. I foresee many injuries for the poor mage. Pull a sword in a crowd of already antsy anyones.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! You could improve this answer by including quotes and/or references for your statements. Take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) if you haven't already, and check out the [help center](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) for more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!